# Variable name in dot notation in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

I want to use variable names in dot notation in Swift.

I'm wrestling with trying to make sense of JSON in Swift, and having a really hard time doing things that are so easy in JS (like cycling through objects, etc).

I have variables of custom types:

```swift
var questionConfiguration: QuestionConfiguration
var priorityConfiguration: PriorityConfiguration
```

Each of these types has an attribute, `displayOrder`, I want to access this dynamically. I have tried various things, including the following (`i` is a variable of type Int):

```swift
var configs = [self.questionConfiguration, self.priorityConfiguration]
print([configs[i]].displayOrder)
```

```swift
var configs = ["questionConfiguration", "priorityConfiguration"]
print([configs[i]].displayOrder)
```

How can I achieve this?

EDIT:

```swift
struct QuestionConfiguration: Codable {
    var displayOrder: Int
}

struct PriorityConfiguration: Codable {
    var displayOrder: Int
}
```

Comment: Can you add the declarations of `QuestionConfiguration` and/or `PriorityConfiguration` to your sample code?  The extra brackets around `configs[I]` look wrong.

Comment: @ScottThompson, sure, I've edited the post. There are a couple more variables in each but that wouldn't affect the MWE. No other code (just `import Foundation`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a protocol for same property name then you can access it easily

```
protocol SameProp {
    var displayOrder: Int {get set}
}

class QuestionConfiguration : SameProp {
     var displayOrder : Int = 4
}

class PriorityConfiguration : SameProp {
     var displayOrder : Int = 6
 }

var questionConfiguration: QuestionConfiguration = QuestionConfiguration()
var priorityConfiguration: PriorityConfiguration = PriorityConfiguration()

var configs = [questionConfiguration, priorityConfiguration] as [SameProp]
for elements in configs{
    print(elements.displayOrder) // will print 4 and 6
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift is very particular about data types and I suspect you are experiencing challenges because of it.

When you do this:

`var configs = [self.questionConfiguration, self.priorityConfiguration]`

In Swift, all the elements in an array have to have the same type. You've not given Swift any hints about what types this array should contain so the compiler has to infer a type. `QuestionConfiguration` and `PriorityConfiguration` are two different types. So the compiler is likely to infer that `configs` is of type `[Any]` also called `Array<Any>`.

Then you try something like this:

`configs[i].displayOrder` (not sure why your code has the extra brackets)

But `configs[i]` is inferred to be of type `Any` and that type doesn't have a `displayOrder` property so the compiler complains.

You need to tell the compiler that these types share some properties.  One way to do that would be to add a `protocol` that describes what they share:

```
protocol DisplayOrderable {
  var displayOrder: Int { get }
}


struct QuestionConfiguration: DisplayOrderable, Codable {
    var displayOrder: Int
}

struct PriorityConfiguration: DisplayOrderable, Codable {
    var displayOrder: Int
}
```

then you could use

```
var configs: [any DisplayOrderable] = [self.questionConfiguration, self.priorityConfiguration]
```

And `configs[i].displayOrder` should work.